# Android: Problem with SQLite query

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a database containing an Animal table, with columns for _id, name, biography.

I am trying to query the database for a particular biography depending on the animal the user has selected(from a list), problem is the cursor will only ever return the first biography in the database, or none at all.

Can anyone see what the problem might be, or offer some helpful suggestions, I'd be most grateful.

```
 // Code for obtaining position
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
        Intent animalIntent = new Intent(this, Animal.class);
        animalIntent.putExtra("pos", position);
        startActivity(animalIntent);    
    }
```

// query the database for bio, where KEY_ROWID is queried by "position" of item on list.
myCursor = dbm.getBio(position);

```
    if(myCursor.moveToFirst()){

    // querying the cusor, retrieve in index of column BIOGRAPHY, store as column index.
        int bio_index = myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MyDBManager.KEY_BIOGRAPHY);

        // return the string from the cursor @ column index
    String bio = myCursor.getString(bio_index);

    // find textview 
        animalBio = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bio);

        // Set textView to value of string returned from myCursor @ bio_index
    animalBio.setText(bio);
    }
```

// This method will always return the first value stored in the database biography stored in the database 
public Cursor getBio(int position){

```
    return qmDB.query(ANIMAL_TABLE, new String[]{
            KEY_ROWID,
            KEY_BIOGRAPHY,
            },
            KEY_ROWID,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null);
}
```

I have tried other variations such as KEY_ROWID = "+" = position, KEY_ROWID = "?", converting the position to string, passing in position as type long, hard coding a number, etc.

So you see I feel the problem is with the query statement, it is simply not returning any other row than the first, or IF it does, it is not displayed!

SOLUTION:

Remember to update your database on the application.

Comment: Could you please provide the code for obtaining `position`?

Comment: sure pecka, I have updated the original post with the code, and also some new explanations on how I have approached the problem.

Comment: I have managed to solve the problem, as it turned out I had not updated the DB.4 days and countless hours of frustration, not going to forget this in a hurry... thanks to everyone for the helpful advice.

Answer (score 0):

Very much as in a JDBC ResultSet, you need to call the 'moveToNext()' method for your cursor to move. Example:

```
while(myCursor.moveToNext()){
   bio = myCursor.getString(bio_index);
   // etc...
}
```

Cursor JavaDoc: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html

> public abstract boolean moveToNext ()
>
> Since: API Level 1
>
> Move the cursor to
> the next row. This method will return
> false if the cursor is already past
> the last entry in the result set.
>
> Returns: whether the move succeeded

Comment: Hi Vicente, there is no need to make use of moveToNext() as I only want to return a single bio of a particular animal chosen.The flow of the app is as follows: List of animals->animal page(including picture, and 'biography' and 'back' buttons) -> animal biography page. So you see, I query database based on the position of the animal on the list.I am using this position to map to _ID field in the table and return the appropriate biography.

Comment: Got it. Can we see your List Handler?

Comment: By listHandler are you talking about the list Activity? I ran a test to see if the correct position was being passed correctly and it turned out ok.

Comment: Then I think you should check KEY_ROWID refers to the appropriated column. And (this shouldn't affect the result but who knows) using the 4th parameter which is like a setParameter from the resultset (you can also use Question Marks here). I also think you're missing something in your example code 'cos the array closes right after a comma, AFAIK it's not a valid Java syntax.

Answer (score 0):

do something like this:

```
Cursor c=null;
c=;
try {
if (c!=null) {
for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {

}

}
} finally {
if (c!=null) {
c.close();
}
}
```

Comment: Hi Pentium, I have tried to fix the problem with this code and it did not work!I can access the database no problem, and it will return information to me.I just get the feeling the problem has to do with the row id and positioning of the list item..

Comment: We don't have information about `position`. If my hunch is correct that would be a sequential number probably from a selection list. You need to jump your adapter to that position and retrieve the unique id of the record on that position, and pass the unique id and not the position.

Comment: Your hunch would be correct, however I am not using an adapter, rather I am using the code above to return the cursor, retrieve the column index of biography, and set textView to value of biography.Is it possible to do it in this manner?

Comment: As said, we don't know what values(from where) `position` gets. But maybe that is not an unique id, and in this situation you need to use the `LIMIT OFFSET,1` syntax, to skip X rows from the beginning. The `position` in this syntax would be the Offset, and it will be Zero for the first row. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in the way you are making your sql query. The following code should solve your problem.

```
public Cursor getBio(int position) {
    return qmDB.query(ANIMAL_TABLE, new String[]{KEY_ROWID,KEY_BIOGRAPHY}, "KEY_ROWID=?",  new String[]{ position }, null, null, null);
}
```

Comment: Hi Raunak,Thanks for the suggestion, I have tried this approach and unfortunately it did not work!

Answer (score 0):

This may seem insulting but use sqlitebrowser and make sure that your unique id's really are unique (perhaps you forgot to autoincrement?) Your code present looks fine.

Comment: Hi Ian, my create statement has included an auto increment and I know there is more than one row as a list is filled with a number of animals, from the same table.

Comment: i think you edited your querying method. The third parameter should definitely be (KEY_ROWID + "="+ position) unless you use the ? mark syntax.

Comment: Yup your correct!There was no problem with my query at all, turns out the whole problem was based on the database bing outdated..grr.

Comment: hm, well please conclude this thread by giving your solution in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you had a list, I assume you are using the onListItemClick method. So get the name (position 1 according to your table) from the item the user clicked.

```
@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Cursor o = (Cursor) this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        dbm.getBio(o.getString(1));
    }
```

Your query using the position is flawed in my opinion. This is what I think you want to do in your getBio method:

```
public Cursor getBio(String name) {
    return this.dbm.query(ANIMAL_TABLE, new String[]{KEY_BIOGRAPHY},"name='" + name + "'", null, null, null, null);
}
```